# I am trying to use the replace function in python but am having some problems

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program for my father so he can easily change passwords at his work. He has to change a list of passwords so the pattern would be like 'abcde123' to 'bcdef234' and so on.

I figured out for the most part how to code it:

```
code = input("Enter code")

code = code.replace("z", "a")
code = code.replace("y", "z")
code = code.replace("x", "y")
code = code.replace("w", "x")
code = code.replace("v", "w")
code = code.replace("u", "v")
code = code.replace("t", "u")
code = code.replace("s", "t")
code = code.replace("r", "s")
code = code.replace("q", "r")
code = code.replace("p", "q")
code = code.replace("o", "p")
code = code.replace("n", "o")
code = code.replace("m", "n")
code = code.replace("l", "m")
code = code.replace("k", "l")
code = code.replace("j", "k")
code = code.replace("i", "j")
code = code.replace("h", "i")
code = code.replace("g", "h")
code = code.replace("f", "g")
code = code.replace("e", "f")
code = code.replace("d", "e")
code = code.replace("c", "d")
code = code.replace("b", "c")
code = code.replace("a", "b")

print code
```

In the first line it says to change any 'z' to 'a'. In the second to last line it says to change any 'a' to 'b'. When you try and run this code, when you type in a 'z' it will automatically go to an 'b'. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

EDIT: Yes, I also realized it was because I added a last line of code that changes the previous line into a b.

Comment: Surely because after changing "z" to "a", your last line will encounter an "a" (which was originally "z" but already changed) and change it to a "b"

Comment: (This is not on topic but I should mention that this does not sound like good password practice! You would be much better off randomising every time)

Comment: @JackParkinson I realized that the first time, but since I'm still a beginner I'm having a lot of trouble understanding a lot of the answers I found online

Comment: @JackParkinson (Yes, that's true, but my dad has to change one letter because the systems he uses do that and they reset monthly. So he has to change it to log in again. I do agree, it would be better to just give random passwords!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running your replacement on new data! Here's an example where we iterate over the characters given and replace them once, that prevents the problem you described:

```
code = input("Enter code")

key = {'z': 'a',
       'y': 'z',
       'x': 'y',
       'w': 'x',
       'v': 'w',
       'u': 'v',
       't': 'u',
       's': 't',
       'r': 's',
       'q': 'r',
       'p': 'q',
       'o': 'p',
       'n': 'o',
       'm': 'n',
       'l': 'm',
       'k': 'l',
       'j': 'k',
       'i': 'j',
       'h': 'i',
       'g': 'h',
       'f': 'g',
       'e': 'f',
       'd': 'e',
       'c': 'd',
       'b': 'c',
       'a': 'b'
       }

new = list()

for c in list(code):
    new.append(key[c])

print(''.join(new))
```

**Edit:**

Reading your example a bit more closely, it seems you just want to rotate the letters one position - no key necessary for that! And we can now easily adapt this to support numbers, special characters... anything you want!

```
from string import ascii_letters

code = input("Enter code")
charset = ascii_letters
new = list()

for c in list(code):
    i = charset.find(c)
    new.append(charset[i - 1])

print(''.join(new))
```

Comment: Thank you, but instead of doing an [i - 1] it was better to do [i + 1].

Comment: @DeeDee One problem with `[i+1]` you'll encounter is with the z - you won't circle back to a, while using `[i-1]` will circle back to the last item if you start with a

Comment: Actually, when I did this, it did circle back to a but only makes it capitalized. Still working on making it stay lower case it.

Comment: Ah right! ascii is A-Za-z... so then you can just do `lower(''.join(new)))` instead

Answer (score 1):

This is simple enough to do in one line:

```
new = [chr(ord(char) + 1) if char != 'z' else 'a' for char in code]
```

This increases the ascii value of each char by 1. If the char is 'z' then it is set as 'a'.

The `ord()` function gets the ascii value of a char

The `chr()` function returns the corresponding char from an ascii value

Comment: Nice, didn't think of that!